# Wrong answer for the sum of elements in array

Tags: c

I need to return the sum of all elements in an array (`values[i]`) given to us from an excel file. I can only get the sum to equal to 0.

I think I'm missing something or maybe a small error somewhere that I can't spot.

File example:
[rainfaillupdated.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxouq.png)

```
YearMonth rainfall(mm)
195801  40
195802  101.6
195803  23.4
195804  29.9
195805  103.9
195806  168.5
195807  109.5
195808  140.6
195809  128.8
195810  52
195811  45.4
195812  90.3
```

Excel file example ^^

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  // Data Declaration
  char header[40] = "";
  int size_of_array = 768;
  int dates[768] = { 0 };
  float values[768] = { 0 };
  float sum = 0;
  float avg;
  int i;
  FILE* input_fptr;

  //  Opens file
  input_fptr = fopen("rainfallupdated.csv", "r");
  if (input_fptr == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error - could not open the file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Read in the header line from file
  fgets(header, sizeof(header), input_fptr);
  printf("%s", header);

  // Read 768 lines of data from the file
  for (i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
  {
    fscanf(input_fptr, "%d,%f\n", &dates[i], &values[i]);
    printf("%d\t %g\n", dates[i], values[i]);

  }
  fclose(input_fptr);

  // Information for the user
  printf("YearMonth , Rainfall in mm\n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("Example: 198702 = February of 1987.\n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("\n");

  for (i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++);
  {
    sum = sum + values[i];
  }

  printf("Sum of all rainfall values = %.2f\n", sum);
  printf("\n");

  avg = sum / size_of_array;
  
  printf("Average rainfall value = %.2f\n", avg);
  printf("\n");
  printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"Sum of all rainfall values = %.2f\n"` -> `"Sum of all rainfall values = %d\n"`. Closing as a typo.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the values for rainfall are in decimal format

Comment: @Darragh don't describe stuff, [edit] and show it instead. BTW: `decimal format` is absolutely unclear.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the file im scanning from has decimal values so i use "float" right? I'm literally new to coding.

Comment: @Darragh now it's like before: your're using `avg` without never having assigned anything to it. The original issue will be resolved if you apply the modification suggestd in my second comment. And yes, you probably need to use `float` here, although I'm not sure how the `rainfallupdated.csv` looks like. Do what I suggested and [edit] and show the first few lines of this file.

Comment: OK, so now you've changed `int sum` to `int float` which will solve the initial issue (not displaying the sum corectly)

Comment: It should be OK now. But consider `avg = sum / 768;` -> `avg = sum / size_of_array;`

Comment: Thanks for posting the contents of the file, but last but not least: for your next question here: don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text. The important thing here is not what your Excel screen looks like but what the content of the your csv file is.

Comment: @Jabberwocky my bad. New here :)

Comment: @Jabberwocky I changed the code but now both sum and avg are displaying 0.00

Comment: @Darragh as requested over and over again: show the first few lines of your csv file as properly formatted text also show the first few lines of the program's output also as properly formatted text.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i dont know how to do that. Tried searching for tutorials but I'm lost. :/

Comment: @Darragh OK, Excel is trying to be "helpful" here and also puts an image version into the clipboard. Proceed as follows: copy the cells in Excel with Ctrl+C, then open some text editor like Notepad, paste it there, mark it and copy it again. Now you can paste it into stackoverflow as text.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I got an example of the csv file posted now.

Comment: `fscanf(input_fptr, "%d,%f\n"...` there are no commas in input! I suggest you dump `fscanf()` and use exclusively `fgets()` for user (or file) input.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

---

**Problem number 1**

There is an excess `;` in this line:

```
for (i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++);
```

Which makes your code equivalent to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
{
   // do nothing
}
sum = sum + values[i];
```

Simply remove it.

---

**Problem number 2**

You need to remove the `,` from the format string:

```
fscanf(input_fptr, "%d,%f\n", &dates[i], &values[i]);
```

Change `"%d,%f\n"` to `"%d %f\n"`